# Forcing WooCommerce customers to create account before checking out

Tags: hooks

I'd like to force my site subscribers/members to create an account (and/or log in) before they can checkout. How would I go about doing this? I understand that I would be using something like '''action hook “template_redirect”'''

But I'm a beginner and have no idea how to set this up. Any help?

Comment: You shouldn't need hooks to do this. It's covered under WooCommerce > Settings > Accounts & Privacy.

Comment: I want them to have a WP log-in account / password as they will need this to view content on the site. But I don't see where/how this happens on the checkout page

Comment: I'm looking at the checkout field editor plug-in ... perhaps this will work?

Comment: It won’t. Please look at the settings Howdy pointed you to. You can just tick a box to require users to have an account to checkout, and there’s an option to let them register during checkout.

Comment: To clarify @Howdy_McGee's comment, there is an option in WooCommerce under Settings > Accounts & Privacy for **Guest checkout**. As standard this box is ticked and allow customers to place orders without an account. If you untick that box, they'll be forced to create an account first.

Andrew, reading your first comment, could you clarify what you are trying to achieve? Is this a members only site you're trying to setup? Does Howdy's comment solve your problem? If not, why not? Could you use these comments to clarify your question?

Comment: Thank you. Using these settings solved the problem!